# What is the status of the argument by analogy now?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, argumentation, explanation

Now what about the argument by analogy in favor of the existence of other minds.
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal
It is written in the article that he was heavily criticized and became unusable. That is, its use is irrational?

Answer (score 1):

Occam's Razor has nothing to do with the argument by analogy. The argument by analogy looks at how two things are similar in some respect and then argues for a further similarity based on that. Occam's razor has to do with picking the simpler hypothesis out of a series of competing hypotheses.

Your piece on the other hand is essentially an opinion piece behind when the argument by analogy seems to work and when it isn't. That is a subjective matter so I'm not even sure what is being asked here.

Comment: I want to ask if the argument by analogy is valid now. The article states that the argument has been subjected to strong criticism and has become unusable. Is this argument unusable now?

Comment: The article is ultimately an opinion piece

Comment: "Your piece on the other hand is essentially an opinion piece behind when the argument by analogy seems to work and when it isn't. "-  could you explain how to understand this?